How to Fix AWS Cognito Lambda Trigger Returning {####} Instead of the Correct OTP?
I’m using AWS Cognito for user authentication and have implemented a Lambda function to send verification emails via the SendGrid email service. The reason for using Lambda and SendGrid is that my requests to move AWS SES to production mode were always rejected.
However, I’m facing an issue with retrieving the OTP in my trigger. When I access event.request.codeParameter, it returns {####} instead of the actual OTP.
Here is the Lambda function:
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
require('dotenv').config();

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Received event:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    const msg = {
        to: event.request.userAttributes.email,
        from: 'noreply@myapp.com', 
        subject: 'Verify Your Email',
        text: `Please verify your email by entering the following code: ${event.request.codeParameter}`,
        html: `<strong>Please verify your email by entering the following code: ${event.request.codeParameter}</strong>`
    };

    try {
        await sgMail.send(msg);

        callback(null, event);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        callback(error, null);
    }
};

and here is the received event
2024-05-08T17:48:27.926Z INFO   Received event: 
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "eu-north-1",
    "userPoolId": "String",
    "userName": "String",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "String"
    },
    "triggerSource": "CustomMessage_SignUp",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "sub": "40e32520-....",
            "cognito:email_alias": "a@gmail.com",
            "email_verified": "false",
            "cognito:user_status": "UNCONFIRMED",
            "email": "a@gmail.com"
        },
        "codeParameter": "{####}",
        "linkParameter": "{##Click Here##}",
        "usernameParameter": null
    },
    "response": {
        "smsMessage": null,
        "emailMessage": null,
        "emailSubject": null
    }
}


How can I fix the Lambda trigger to correctly retrieve the OTP instead of {####}?
Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Cognito supplies passwords and authorization codes encrypted using a KMS key, so you must decrypt the code using the kms key before sending it via Sendgrid.
The AWS docs below provide details on configuring cognito to use the kms key and a code sample showing how to decrypt the authorization token.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html#enable-custom-email-sender-lambda-trigger
Hope this helps
